# How to Simplify a Markov chain in order to estimate the average number of transitions to reach to a final state?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Is there any approach to approximate the expected number of transitions to complete a Markov chain without knowing the exact transition probabilities?
The reason I ask this is because I want to calculate the average number of events that can be modeled by some transitions in a Markov chain. The probabilities of transition are both very complicated to derive and the graph is very complecated. I don't need the exact model of the system though.
Let me put the question this way: How can I simplify the Markov chain such that it can give a good approximation for the average number of required transitions to reach to a final state? It is no problem if it poorly models the system in any other sense.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't know the transition probabilities, what **do** you know that could possibly contribute to an answer?

Comment: Well, assume I have to reach to state (0,-,-) to complete the process, beginning from state (S,0,0). the second and third elements of the state vector are open ended (infinite number of states) and it is not important what their value are, when the first element reaches 0. I was thinking to combine some of the states and represent them as a single state, or use a bound to represent an optimistic or pessimistic case that finally leads to an approximation. Maybe this sounds silly, but I am stuck with a complex model and need to approximate. Just don't know how!